# Convert wav with multiple data chunk to single data chunk

Tags: conversion, wav, data

I need to convert a wav file with multiple "data" chunks to a wav file with a single data chunk which includes all others. I will do this operation for thousands of files, there's a tool to do this?

Comment: @DoritoStyle  no i have one file wav mono channel,  with one header and multiple data chuncks